# Case Sensitivity in SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

I am designing a basic email and password form on my application. It uses usernames and passwords found in a database linked to it. I am experiencing 1 problem, how do I make it take case sensitivity into account? Like for instance:

Correct Details: email: matt@gmail.com Password: gordan123

However it allows the password to be: Gordan123, GORDAN123 and GoRdAn123 etc. How do I make it so it only accepts the one in the database with case sensitivity taken into account?

Sorry I don't know how to describe this problem better. Here's the code:

```
 SQL_Str = "CREATE TABLE Table_UserDetails (UserImageLocation TEXT, FirstName VARCHAR(25), LastName VARCHAR(25), Gender VARCHAR(6), EmailAddress VARCHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY, UserPassword VARCHAR(25))"
        dbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SQL_Str, dbConnector)
        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

 Private Sub BtnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnLogin.Click
    If LoginDetailsSearch() = True Then
        FormMain.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("The E-Mail address or password you entered is not valid, please check your entries and try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End If

End Sub
Function LoginDetailsSearch() As Boolean
    dbConnector.Open()
    SQL_Str = "SELECT * FROM Table_UserDetails"

    dbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL_Str, dbConnector)
    dbDataAdapter.Fill(dbDataSet, "Users")

    For Each Record In dbDataSet.Tables("Users").Rows
        If txtEmail.Text = Record.Item(4) And txtPassword.Text = Record.Item(5) Then
            SelectedUserFirstName = Record.Item(1)
            SelectedUserLastName = Record.Item(2)
            dbConnector.Close()
            Return True
        End If
    Next

    dbConnector.Close()
    Return False
End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't store a password in plain text. Store the hash or salted hash of the password and compare your hashes.

Comment: hooray for not storing in plain text

Comment: I'm not trying to make this system secure yet, I just want it to make comparisons and work properly

Comment: If you use hashes, you won't need to worry about case sensitivity because those will generate different hashes. It'll be easier to implement, too, since it'll be secure from the start.

Comment: There are so many other issues with the OP's code.  For example, selecting the entire `Table_UserDetails` and then iterating through it.  That's not going to scale well.

Comment: If you have no choice but what you're trying to do, you'll need to do a string comparison in VB.NET using what the user entered and the database value. (I believe you can use String.Contains) Understand this is a bad idea, and hashing the password using something like MD5 isn't going to take more than a couple minutes to implement and go a long way toward securing your app. I found a working code snippet in 10 minutes through a Google search.